# Why is the application indicator for LanSchool not showing?

Tags: indicator, lanschool

I am trying to setup LanSchool on Ubuntu 14.04 MATE. Everything installs and I can verify that `studentwnd` and `student-indicator` are running. However, there is no indicator in the top panel. The indicator shows with Unity and GNOME fallback in 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working simply by installing the `python-appindicator` package. The indicator came right up!